# No lockfile found. Unable to read locked packages Magento2.4.3 composer update issue

Tags: composer, docker, magento2.4.3, composer-update

/app/magento2# composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
In Laminas\DependencyPlugin\DependencyRewriterV2::onPrePoolCreate
Updating dependencies
Nothing to modify in lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Nothing to install, update or remove
Package container-interop/container-interop is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use psr/container instead.
Generating autoload files
composer/package-versions-deprecated: Generating version class...
composer/package-versions-deprecated: ...done generating version class
92 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!

> php ./vendor/bin/ece-tools schema:generate || true

In Container.php line 99:

No lockfile found. Unable to read locked packages

In Locker.php line 279:

No lockfile found. Unable to read locked packages

Please help on this issue

[image]

Comment: please any one help on this...Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and after searching for a while I noticed that my composer.lock file was missing from my project. after adding it back from local history, the issue got fixed.